# Is there a way to flag or warn about a review-abuse?

Tags: support, review, review-abuse

I was reviewing this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1687022

Though I may admit that this edit was minor... There are two reviewers that classifies that edit as introducing spam, when it's not.

I felt like it was reviewer abuse. I wanted to flag that, but did not find the button.

What is the common way to report that ?

EDIT: well I'm wrong the edit was to be considered spam. Thanks for the answer and downvotes. **However you don't answer "what is the common way to report review abuse" ? Simply meta ? The answer can satisfy me, but at least tell it.**

Comment: The entire sentence reads `This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.` And the edit *does* deface the post a bit, don't you think? It removes its formatting. (Maybe by accident, but still)

Comment: What I think it's that no one has answered my question. I wanted to know the mean to flag review abuse to a moderator. Maybe it's simply to report it on meta like I did. I thought a flag link would be good. Of course I have to agree that I was wrong thinking there was a review abuse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those reviewers were entirely correct to reject the edit; the changes made were inappropriate.

- The change note reads "edit edit edit"; not telling us much, but indicates to me the editor was not taking the edit suggestion seriously.
- It removed whitespace from the start of the lines, completely breaking the formatting of the code in the post.

No, no spam (inappropriate promotion) was introduced, but the rejection reason is not limited to just spam. The rejection reason, in full, is:

> This edit introduces spam, **defaces the post in some way**, or is otherwise inappropriate.

Emphasis mine; this edit was rejected because it defaced the post.

If you come across a *legitimate* case of review abuse (e.g. a user that is rejecting *everything* it reviews with the same rejection reason), pick one post that the user reviewed, and flag it for moderator attention. Use the 'other' option and explain in the post what you found.

Comment: Well obviously I was wrong considering the review was an abuse. However my question was rather "What is common way to report review abuse" ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: It would have been better if you ask the question in general, since linking to example will be taken as talking about a specific instance.